# generate thumbnail on uploading image using zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, image-manipulation

I am back again with a question in zend framework. Can someone explain me, how to generate thumbnail images in zend framework after uploading an image.

Thanks!

Comment: workinf with files http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.html

Comment: or build your library like here http://www.pamparam.net/post/resize-zend-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend itself seems will not provide this ability http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Image+-+Eric+Potvin and propose to use http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php.
then you are free to use your own way

Answer (score 2):

Not a purely Zend Framework answer, but lately I have found myself cheating like crazy, as follows.

I install [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) somewhere inside a web-accessible folder, say:

`http://example.com/img/t/phpThumb.php`

I make sure to configure phpThumb to use a cache folder:

`/path/to/myapp/public/img/t/cache`

which I `chmod` to be web-server writable.

Then I have a phpThumb view-helper that allows me to call an original image with some resize parameters:

`<img src="<?php $view->phpThumb($origImgUrl, $desiredWidth, $desiredHeight) ?>">`

All the view helper really does is transform the src url into one that runs through my phpThumb installation, making sure to add the cool (!) zoom-center parameter:

`<img src="/img/t/phpThumb.php?src=origUrl&w=200&h=150&zc=1">`

The first call to this image with these resize params results in a full GD/ImageMagick-driven resize, with the full performance hit. But subsequent calls for that image will pull from cache. Not as good as a request for a truly static image, but usually acceptable for my relatively low-volume purposes.

This is especially useful during design/development, when I am not sure precisely how big I want some front-end, eye-candy image to be. So I can just stash a single, relatively-large verison of my image (say 640x480) out in `public/img/someBigImage.png` and then resize at will.

It's a hack - probably better to perform this resizing on upload, as you are actually asking - but I must admit I have used it in a few spots. Don't tell anybody. ;-)